# How to ensure the same column width on the search results page in a Microsoft List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-lists

The URL of my list is in this format:

```
https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/list-name/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList
```

Using the `?env=WebViewList` suffix on the URL enforces the modern 'Microsoft List' style.

I have made a custom view with custom column widths and set it as the Default view.

By doing this, all items in the list are displayed on one row each - neat and tidy.

Then I search in the top search box, click on the search icon, and the column widths are removed on the search results page.

The columns become narrow and the values in the columns wrap over multiple lines - it looks messy and unprofessional.

How can I ensure the search results page uses the same view (and column widths) as the list?

Comment: How did you fixed column widths in default view, using JSON or any other way? Unfortunately, search results way does not support all functionalities as of default list view in SharePoint.

Comment: As creator of the list, I just drag column width and save view from front end.